# Bootstrap 3 "Desktop" breakpoint's layout is shown, instead of the small one

Tags: windows-phone-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a client's Nokia Lumia 920, the "Desktop" breakpoint's layout is shown, instead of the small one. Why is this? Is Bootstrap 3 handling pixel density in Android and iOS but not on Windows Mobile? Any ideas?

(Windows Phone 8 GDR2 with IE, WXGA (1280 x 768), 332 ppi, Aspect ratio: 15:9, Display size: 4.5")

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML head.:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This tells smaller device browsers how to scale the page.